# How to connect Db2 Federated Views with Hibernate 4?

Tags: db2, federated-table

Can anyone please suggest or help how can we have Hibernate mapping with Federated Views in Db2 Database?

```
Database_1 : TABLENAME001

Database_2 : FV_XXX_TABLENAME [FV is federated view with Database_1 table TABLENAME001]
```

Now when I run through normal JDBC like `select * from FV_XXX_TABLENAME` I get the output. But when I map through Hibernate like `@Table(name ="FV_XXX_TABLENAME")`, Hibernate throws error as:

> "Table Not found: FV_XXX_TABLENAME"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can connect DB2 Federated Views with Hibernate mapping.
I solved the above issue by just removing the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" from the configuration file and Hibernate automatically detected the Federated View tables.